# Using Java Server Pages, how do make a "register" form data after Submiting

Tags: java, jsp

I am starting with Java Server Pages. I want to make a register form which consists from three steps. First page index.jsp is a register form with two fields: Name and Surname. After i complete this two fields i press next and pass to next page PaginaDoi.jsp where i complete Address and Phone Fields. After this i pass next to third page PaginaTrei.jsp where all data is displayed before send to database or step back to modify data.

The main thing i want to do is to store all fields unmodified after i go backward and forward with Next and Back button. For this i made a session and it's work fine, but when i go back from Third Page to Second Page my Name and Surname resets to null.
I stayed about a day to understand where i made a mistake but without succes. Please help me.

I provide the code below:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms["formular"]["nume","prenume"].value;
if(x==null||x==""){
    alert("Toate campurile sunt necesare");
    return false;
}

}
</script>
<title>Formular de inregistrare</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Introduceti datele in campurile respective</h1>
<form name="formular" action="PaginaDoi.jsp" onsubmit="return validateForm()"   method="post">
Nume: <input type="text" name="nume" value="<%=session.getAttribute("FirstName")!=null? session.getAttribute("FirstName"):""%>" maxlength="15"></br>
Prenume: <input type="text" name="prenume" value=" <%=session.getAttribute("LastName")!=null?session.getAttribute("LastName"):""%>"  maxlength="10"></br>
<div id="subm"><input type="submit" value="Inainte"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second Page (PaginaDoi.jsp)**

```
<%String fname=request.getParameter("nume");
session.setAttribute("FirstName",fname);
String lname=request.getParameter("prenume");
session.setAttribute("LastName",lname); 
%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms["formular"]["telefon","adresa"].value;
if(x==null||x==""){
    alert("Toate campurile sunt necesare");
    return false;
}   
}
</script>
<title>Formular de inregistrare</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Introduceti datele in campurile respective</h1>
Nume: <%=session.getAttribute("FirstName")%></br>
Prenume: <%=session.getAttribute("LastName")%></br>
<form name="formular" action="PaginaTrei.jsp" onsubmit="return validateForm()"   method="post">
Telefon: <input type="text" name="telefon" value="   <%=session.getAttribute("ThePhone")!=null?session.getAttribute("ThePhone"):""%>"      maxlength="10"></br>
Adresa: <input type="text" name="adresa" value="  <%=session.getAttribute("TheAddress")!=null?session.getAttribute("TheAddress"):""%>"   maxlength="20"></br>
<div id="subm"><input type="submit" value="Inainte"></div>
</form>
<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
<div id="submInapoi"><input type="submit" value="Inapoi"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Third Page (PaginaTrei.jsp)**

```
<%
String tel=request.getParameter("telefon");
session.setAttribute("ThePhone",tel);
String add=request.getParameter("adresa");
session.setAttribute("TheAddress",add);
%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Datele introduse</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Introduceti datele in campurile respective</h1>
Nume: <%=session.getAttribute("FirstName")%></br>
Prenume: <%=session.getAttribute("LastName")%></br>
Telefon: <%=session.getAttribute("ThePhone")%></br>
Adresa: <%=session.getAttribute("TheAddress")%></br>
<form action="Salveaza.jsp" method="post">
<div id="subm"><input type="submit" value="Trimite"></div>
</form>
<form action="PaginaDoi.jsp" method="post">
<div id="submInapoi"><input type="submit" value="Inapoi"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use framework like spring or any other for mutiform registration

Comment: I tought about it but i want to know if there is a way to do this kind of thing without any frameworks?

Comment: You can do but it takes lot of time to code you have to think each and everything like if user click back button values should not clear.which is time waste process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend doing the way you are, if you look, in your second page, you are setting the attributes in session based on your request parameters.  If you have a link on the third form that goes to the second form, your request parameters are going to be null and you are essentially deleting the information from the session at that point.

You would have to do something like:

`if (tel != null) session.setAttribute("ThePhone",tel);`

etc.